# Unable to rollback to the current revision - on previous rev

Tags: bug

I was trying to roll back to revision 2 of [a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/98675/revisions) because, in revision 3, code formatting was introduced inappropriately in multiple places and I did not want to start editing from there, and at least one type is still present.

After confirming that I wanted to roll back to version 2, the system prompted a message: `Unable to rollback to the current version`. I checked the question in case someone else had had the same problem with this third revision and in the mean time rolled back, but the version displayed in "normal view" was the third revision.

On second and third try I cannot roll back to 2. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

If it makes a difference: revision 2 was an approved edit, revision 3 a direct edit by a 2K+ user.

I can of course undo the (many) inappropriate changes in rev 3, but for now I left the question in peace in case the bug only can be reproduced with the current 3 revisions' data as input.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to reliably reproduce it?

Comment: @Braiam Yes. I did try at least 3 time times on that day, also after navigating away. I normally don't make screenshots on first try. I could attempt it again but decided not to, and I will wait until someone who can look at the code and/or logs notices the bug report.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue on another post. I wanted to roll back to revision 2 and got the message you show. So, I rolled back to the first revision and then rolled back again to the second.

This works as a temporary workaround but, unfortunately, it also raises an automatic flag for a rollback war. Presumably because of the two consecutive roll backs. I, and I hope the other mods, can deal with that though, so for the time being I suggest you do that. Presumably the SE team will be fixing it soon.

Comment: I'll keep the post as is for now in the hope that that helps resolve the issue. I think that fixing (and allowing the issue to be fixed) is important. I had never thought about rollback to one version one though as an alternative.

Comment: @Anthon please do. It's certainly a bug and should be fixed. I just wanted to let you know of the workaround I found and also wanted to confirm the bug.